# Failed to run Python3 http.server on Docker's container

Tags: python, docker

I'm trying to create a Docker container which runs a Python http.server listening on port 8000. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 AS focal

WORKDIR /usr/src/server
COPY . .

RUN apt update && apt-get install -y build-essential python python3 zip net-tools iptables sudo curl

CMD ["python3", "-m http.server", "8000"]
```

First, I successfully built the image: `docker build -t py_server .`

Then I tried to run the image as a container: `docker run --rm -p 8000:8000 py_server`

But the following error was thrown:

```
/usr/bin/python3: Error while finding module specification for ' http.server' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ' http')
```

Not sure why python3 wasn't able to find the `http` module when specified with CMD in the Dockerfile. I tested whether python3 in the container has `http.server` by directly executing the command using bash on the py_server image, and it worked:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -p 8000:8000 py_server bash
root@d3426b37cf2e:/usr/src/cs435_mp1_server# python3 -m http.server 8000
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 (http://0.0.0.0:8000/) ...
```

I'm very confused about this.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed that there was a space in front of "http.server" which made python3 unable to find the module.

I edited the CMD line on my Dockerfile and it is working now:

```
CMD ["python3", "-m", "http.server", "8000"]
```

Still not very sure why a space was previously added in front of "http.server" though.

Comment: Because you included it in a single shell word.  You'd get the same effect if you ran `"python" "-m http.server" "8000"` in a non-Docker Python setup.